# How to Select execute 'dynamic sql' from stored procedure?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In a stored procedure I'm constructing dynamic SQL which is available in a variable like below:

```
DECLARE @SqlQry VARCHAR(max) 
SELECT @SqlQry = @SQL  --@SQL has dynamic SQL already.
```

I can execute this SQL statement like this:

```
exec (@SqlQry);
```

My question is how to `select` and returned results of this execution. I want to return these results just like a normal select statement. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your statement is a select it will return the dataset as a regular select would.

```
DECLARE @SqlQry NVARCHAR(max) = 'select wtvr from wtvr'


exec sp_executesql @SqlQry
```